# Ensure consistent button height when UIButton.Configuration.showsActivityIndicator is true and false

Tags: ios, uikit, uibutton

With the following code, the button height is 28.33 while using the default large dynamic type size. When you tap the button to enable `showsActivityIndicator` the height unexpectedly increases to 34.33. The inconsistent button height is more pronounced the smaller your font size and the larger the user's dynamic type size.

```
let button = UIButton(configuration: {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    config.title = "Button"
    config.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer {
        var container = $0
        container.uiKit.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        return container
    }
    return config
}())
button.addAction(UIAction() { _ in
    button.configuration?.showsActivityIndicator = true
}, for: .touchUpInside)
```

The problem appears to be that the button height is determined by the content insets, and those insets are relative to the largest content in the button. Initially the only content in the button is the title text so it has a small height, then the activity indicator is added which has a larger height than the title text, and thus the button height increases in order to ensure the content insets are respected relative to the tallest content. Is there a way to fix this such that the button height will remain unchanged in its non-loading and loading state (aside from forcing a fixed height constraint)? Perhaps a way to change the content insets to always be relative to the activity indicator height in the non-loading state?

Answer (score 0):

One option -- might work for you...

From Apple's docs:

> **showsActivityIndicator**
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether the button displays an activity indicator instead of an image.

The default size of the "spinner" is `20.5 x 20.5` on a @2x display, `20.333... x 20.333...` on a @3x display.

So, we could set a clear image at that size, and adjust the `.contentInsets` so the title is horizontally centered when the Activity Indicator is not showing.

Something like this:

```
let v: CGFloat = 20.0 + 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
// create a clear image
let img = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: .init(width: v, height: v)).image { _ in }
let button = UIButton(configuration: {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    config.title = "Button"
    config.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer {
        var container = $0
        container.uiKit.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        return container
    }
    config.image = img
    // default instets are 7, 12, 7, 12
    //  so we need to add the image width to the right
    config.contentInsets = .init(top: 7.0, leading: 12.0, bottom: 7.0, trailing: 12.0 + v)
    return config
}())

button.addAction(UIAction() { _ in
    button.configuration?.showsActivityIndicator.toggle()
}, for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

**Edit**

There does not appear to be any property to set that would give you the control you're looking for...

You *could* use the above code (clear image) and update the image on Trait change...

Or -- kind of a "brute-force" workaround that, again, ***might*** work for you:

Create a button (with matching properties), either hidden or positioned outside the view, and set its `config.showsActivityIndicator = true` ... then constrain the Height of your **visible** button to the Height of the **non-visible** button.

Comment: The activity indicator size changes with dynamic type, so this only works if you're using the large text size.

Comment: @JordanH - good point. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: That’s an interesting idea that would work, very gross, but it’d work ha